# Multi line replace in SED

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I know there are quite a few questions asked on this topic. But I need help in a case basis. This is my scenario. I am having a file with the following string

```
TRACE(HELLO_WORLD, GEN, INFO, "Hello world")
TRACE(
    HELLO_WORLD, GEN, INFO, "Hello World")
```

I want to match all the lines containing `HELLO_WORLD` and in those lines I want to change `TRACE` to `TRACE_CLEANUP` in sed.

My sed command `sed -i '/HELLO_WORLD/s/TRACE/TRACE_CLEANUP/g' abc.txt` matches the first case but not second.

Can you please help get the proper command.

Thanks

Chid

Comment: Can you try this: `cat abc.txt | grep 'HELLO_WORLD' | sed -i 's/TRACE/TRACE_CLEANUP/g' abc.txt`

Comment: Nope. It doesnt work. How do I pipe it to SED? It complains about missing fiilename

Comment: Oh sorry, try adding the file name to the end of the sed command.

Comment: Still no. In that case, sed replaces all instances of TRACE to TRACE_CLEANUP. In this case, there is no use of piping the result of first two commands to SED right? We are not using it.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on single lines - why do you feel you need to use it for this problem? Awk would be a far more natural choice.

Comment: Oops. I was trying SED because thats what I used for find and replace. Can you help me with the command for awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/TRACE\(([[:space:]]*HELLO_WORLD\)/TRACE_CLEANUP\1/g' file
TRACE_CLEANUP(HELLO_WORLD, GEN, INFO, "Hello world")
TRACE_CLEANUP(
    HELLO_WORLD, GEN, INFO, "Hello World")
```

#### How it works

- `H;1h;$!d;x;`

  This reads the whole file in at once.

  If your file were huge (too big for memory), we would want a different approach.  If it is not huge, this approach is quite simple.
- `s/TRACE\(([[:space:]]*HELLO_WORLD\)/TRACE_CLEANUP\1/g`

  This looks for `TRACE(` followed by any whitespace followed by `HELLO_WORLD` and substitutes in `TRACE_CLEANUP`.  The final `g` means that this substitution is done "globally," meaning as many times as needed.

Comment: I am getting d: Event not found

Comment: Wow. i got it now. I changed to BASH shell.

Comment: Thanks. Very smart. I wish I could write these monstorous things on my own

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -e 'undef $/;
         $s = <>;
         $s =~ s/TRACE(\(\s*HELLO_WORLD)/TRACE_CLEANUP$1/g;
         print $s;
        ' input > output
```

- `undef $/` makes Perl read the whole input at once.
- <> reads the input.
- `s///` works similarly as in sed.

Comment: Thanks choroba. In my case SED was more suitable.